# change format (add "." for 1000 digits) for data frame with uncertain number of columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with n columns and these columns (if they exist) contain "big" numbers, for example 1234. Now i want to change the values like 1234 to 1.234. I can do it with this:

```
format(round(as.numeric(c(1234)), 1), nsmall=0, big.mark=".", decimal.mark=",")
```

But i want a function for all columns (and its not certain, how many there are), starting with the third column (and every after that), so i tried the following:

```
df[3:ncol(df)] <- format(round(as.numeric(c(df[3:ncol(df)]))), nsmall=0, big.mark=".")
```

This returns me the error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

Does someone know a solution for this and maybe why i get this error?

Regards

Comment: Are the "numbers" of type character to begin with? if not, then you can adjust like this `df[3:ncol(df)] <- format(round(df[3:ncol(df)]), nsmall=0, big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",")`

Comment: error: replacement has 14 items, need 3092. the function should work, but it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
correct=function(x){ format(round(as.numeric(c(x)), 1), nsmall=0, big.mark=".", decimal.mark=",")}
df[,3:ncol(df)]=apply(df[,3:ncol(df)],2,correct) #apply through columns
```

You can change the function `correct` if you don't like the output having quotes